# Make the super number hyper-pyramid

Tags: code-golf, array

## Challenge

Given a positive integer \$n\$, output the \$n\$-dimensional pyramidal list.

## Example

---

\$n = 1\$:

[image]

Objects arranged in a 1D pyramid (line) with side length 1 is just by itself.

So, the output is `{1}`.

---

\$n = 2\$:

[image]

Objects arranged in a 2D pyramid (a triangle) with side length 2 would have one on the first row (cyan), and two on the second row (magenta).

Note, the first row is a 1D pyramid with side length 1 (`{1}`), and the second row is a 1D pyramid with side length 2 (`{1, 1}`).

So, the output is `{{1}, {1, 1}}`.

---

\$n = 3\$:

[image]

Objects arranged in a 3D pyramid with side length 3 would have 3 layers:

- The first layer (cyan) is a 2D pyramid with side length 1. It has one row, which has one object. (`{{1}}`)
- The second layer (magenta) is a 2D pyramid with side length 2; It has two rows: the first row with one object and the second row with two objects. (`{{1}, {1, 1}}`)
- The third layer (yellow) is a 2D pyramid with side length 3; it has three rows: the first row with one object, second with two, and third with three. (`{{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}`)

So, the output is `{{{1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}`.

---

\$n = k\$

This is a \$k\$ dimensional pyramid with side length \$k\$. Each "layer" would be a \$k-1\$ dimensional pyramid, whose side length is its index (1-indexed).

---

### Sample Outputs

```
n  output

1  {1}

2  {{1},
    {1, 1}}

3  {{{1}},
    {{1}, {1, 1}},
    {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}

4  {{{{1}}},                     
    {{{1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}}},
    {{{1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}},
    {{{1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
     {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}}}
```

### Rules

- No [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/60043) as always.
- The innermost values of your list may be anything (does not need to be consistent for all elements), as long as they are not lists.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest submissions in *each* language win!

---

<sup>Note: Graphics generated using Mathematica</sup>

Comment: I hammered this as a dupe since the only difference from the other challenge is that \$a=b\$. However, I upvoted this, since it was pretty hard to find the dupe and only managed to do so when I tried solving it, and this is a good challenge otherwise.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer you're right. Huh, I left this post in [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16698/60043) for 10 days in case this would happen. :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

<sup>[Ha!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46032216#46032216) Of course it is biased towards Mathematica!</sup>

```
Nest[Range,#,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCQ6KDEvPVVHWUc5Vu1/QFFmXolDmoPJfwA)

Comment: When you have time, could you explain how this works? (the `Listable` attribute plays a key role here, and this feature is not common in other languages)

Comment: Sure, I will try to add an explanation tomorrow.